# How to set the precision for a float in Numpy to 52 decimals?

Tags: python, numpy

I need to solve a differential equation numerically, however I have to use a number which is precise up to 52 decimals and I only managed to get 16 decimals with `np.rounddouble`.

I really want to use numpy for this problem, since I was thought so in class, however if it only works in Maple (which my professor used) I would have to write him about this problem.

Any better method to get more than 16 decimals is also appreciated.

Edit:
I tried to use pythons decimals as proposed by you, however after about 16 digits, my number seized to be accurate.

imgur.com/a/ZnjRF2M

Does this have to do with conversion to float between steps?

Last edit: YES it was a conversion to float since I didnt put apostrophs before and after the number!

Comment: `numpy` used fixed size floating point types.

Comment: It reminds me a problem 80 of Project Euler where the task was to calculate sum of first 100 decimal digits of some square roots. And majority of Pythonic solutions were based on setting `decimal.getcontext().prec = 102`

Comment: For Maple like behavior you may want use `sympy` and `mpmath` rather  than `numpy`.

Comment: Just to keep things in perspective for a casual newcomer, to write the Earth-Sun distance with a  1 mm accuracy you need 15 decimal digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use python's `Decimal`. Decimal arithmetic is implemented in software so it doesn't have the speed of a double, but then you'll have this same problem in any language. `Decimal` numbers are generated from some context where you can set precision to any number. There is a default context that works for module level decimals. This code sets the default, builds and array and then does a simple operation on the array.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.getcontext().prec = 52
>>> arr = np.array([Decimal(i) for i in range(10)])
>>> arr
array([Decimal('0'), Decimal('1'), Decimal('2'), Decimal('3'),
       Decimal('4'), Decimal('5'), Decimal('6'), Decimal('7'),
       Decimal('8'), Decimal('9')], dtype=object)
>>> arr + 3
array([Decimal('3'), Decimal('4'), Decimal('5'), Decimal('6'),
       Decimal('7'), Decimal('8'), Decimal('9'), Decimal('10'),
       Decimal('11'), Decimal('12')], dtype=object)
>>>
```

Comment: so basically you make a number based on an array of characters?

Comment: Why use numpy at all then?

Comment: Not quite. `Decimal` is a pretty standard implementation of arbitrary decimal floating point arithmetic. Its commonly used when you don't want the loss of precision you get when you convert to binary floats. For instance, its usually a better choice when calculating decimal things like money. It is displayed as a character string but really its a C byte array. Numpy broadcasts operations to its contained objects, so the "+" turns into calls to `Decimal.__add__`.

Comment: @BramBoeykens no, there is no array of characters anywhere.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - If you like the grouping operations of numpy or other functions implemented in numpy. Its a handy polymorphic use of numpy functionality.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - I'm surprised that numpy doesn't have its own Decimal implementation, really. It should be the favored choice of anyone doing accounting and hoping to avoid binary float coversions and rounding.

Comment: Math on object dtype arrays is slow, and hit-or-miss. `+` may work, but not `np.exp`.

Comment: @hpaulj - but slow compared to what? If you want fixed point arbitrary precision decimal math, this is a decent way to do it.

Comment: hmm i tried to use the ```decimal.getcontext()= 52``` but after some digits my number wasnt correct anymore.

Comment: @BramBoeykens That is because you initialised the decimal with a float. Floating point numbers (double precision or otherwise) are not accurate to the precision you specified. To get the desired accuracy you must initialise it with a string. eg. `Decimal('0.123...')` vs `Decimal(0.123...)`.

Comment: @dunes is right. My example with an integer is okay but if you are starting with numbers that have a fractional component, initialize with a string, not a float. A floating point number is a binary estimation of the decimal literal you pass in.

Comment: @tdelaney slow compared to using a list.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - I don't see any inherent reason why this would be slow. The actual addition is the same in both cases, so it would be the cost of numpy building a new array and broadcasting the addition verses python building a new list in a comprehension. If the array is large or multidimensional, I wouldn't bet which one is faster without timing it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - and people may use numpy or pandas because they like the semantics, even if its not the fastest solution. You see a lot of pandas CSV question here that arguably better implemented using the csv module.

Comment: @tdelaney yeah, and you'll often see me speaking out against them :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can.

"NumPy does not provide a dtype with more precision than C’s long double".
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html

How much precision does a long double give?

"depends on the hardware and on the development environment: specifically, x86 machines provide hardware floating-point with 80-bit precision, and while most C compilers provide this as their long double type,"...

But you want 56 decimals, and 10 to the power of 56 is much more than 2 to the power of 80.

Answer (score 1):

Let's compare some ways of working with `decimal.Decimal`:

```
In [217]: import decimal
In [218]: Decimal = decimal.Decimal
In [219]: alist = [Decimal(i) for i in range(10)]
In [220]: alist
Out[220]: 
[Decimal('0'),
 Decimal('1'),
 Decimal('2'),
 Decimal('3'),
 Decimal('4'),
 Decimal('5'),
 Decimal('6'),
 Decimal('7'),
 Decimal('8'),
 Decimal('9')]
In [221]: arr = np.array(alist)
In [222]: arr
Out[222]: 
array([Decimal('0'), Decimal('1'), Decimal('2'), Decimal('3'),
       Decimal('4'), Decimal('5'), Decimal('6'), Decimal('7'),
       Decimal('8'), Decimal('9')], dtype=object)
```

Some math works fine with object dtype array.  Basically it delegates the action to the objects.  If they implement the right method, great.  If they don't, it will fail (`np.exp(arr)` will fail for nearly every kind of object, even numbers and numpy arrays, because no one implements a `x.exp()` method.)

```
In [223]: arr+10
Out[223]: 
array([Decimal('10'), Decimal('11'), Decimal('12'), Decimal('13'),
       Decimal('14'), Decimal('15'), Decimal('16'), Decimal('17'),
       Decimal('18'), Decimal('19')], dtype=object)
In [224]: timeit arr+10
6.21 µs ± 71.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

But compare that with a list comprehension:

```
In [225]: [x+10 for x in alist]
Out[225]: 
[Decimal('10'),
 Decimal('11'),
 Decimal('12'),
 Decimal('13'),
 Decimal('14'),
 Decimal('15'),
 Decimal('16'),
 Decimal('17'),
 Decimal('18'),
 Decimal('19')]
In [226]: timeit [x+10 for x in alist]
2.23 µs ± 76.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

The object array may be easier to code, but it isn't faster.  The usual scaling disclaimers apply, but I don't think it will make a difference.

Now compare those with regular numeric numpy:

```
In [227]: y = np.arange(10)
In [228]: y+10
Out[228]: array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19])
In [229]: timeit y+10
1.54 µs ± 23.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

---

I have to take one comment back.  `decimal` does implement a `exp` method.

```
In [250]: alist[5].exp()
Out[250]: Decimal('148.4131591025766034211155800')
In [251]: np.exp(arr)
Out[251]: 
array([Decimal('1'), Decimal('2.718281828459045235360287471'),
       Decimal('7.389056098930650227230427461'),
       Decimal('20.08553692318766774092852965'), 
        ...], dtype=object)
In [252]: timeit np.exp(arr)
180 µs ± 6.33 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [254]: timeit [i.exp() for i in alist]
165 µs ± 621 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Again compare that with the pure numpy:

```
In [255]: timeit np.exp(np.arange(10))
4.22 µs ± 107 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

===

Another option is `mpmath`.  The symbolic package `sympy` makes a lot of use of `mpmath`.  It seems to be slower than `decimal`, but it has a lot more mathematical functions.  So for differential equation work it may be better, with or without `sympy`.  Beware of trying to use `scipy` ode solvers with either of these extensions.  `scipy` is an extension of `numpy`, so it's usefulness with `sympy`, `mpmath` (and presumably `decimal`) will be hit-or-miss.

```
In [268]: mlist = [mpmath.mpf(i) for i in range(10)]
In [269]: ten=mpmath.mpf(10)
In [270]: timeit [x+ten for x in mlist]
21.6 µs ± 1.28 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [271]: timeit [mpmath.exp(i) for i in mlist]
101 µs ± 281 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```